# Prove if $\{ a_n \}$ converges and $\{ b_n \}$ is bounded, then $\{ a_n \cdot b_n \}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I need to prove it and say what condition is needed for $\{ a_n\}$ to converge to $\{ a_n \cdot b_n \}$

My attempt

> suppose $\{ a_n \}$ is such that $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n =
> > \Bigg\{ \begin{matrix} 1, n \,\, is \,\, even\\
> > -1, n \,\, is \,\, odd\\ \end{matrix} $
>
> We have that $a_n \rightarrow 1$, $b_n$ is bounded, but $\{ a_n \cdot
> > b_n \}$ does not converge, since $a_n \cdot b_n = \Bigg\{
> > \begin{matrix} 1 + \frac{1}{n}, n \,\, is \,\, even\\
> > -1 -\frac{1}{n}, n \,\, is \,\, odd\\ \end{matrix} $
>
> If $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and $b_n$ is bounded. Then $\{ a_n \cdot b_n
> > \}$  converges and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \{ a_n \cdot b_n \}=0$
> $\blacksquare$

Is this an appropriate prove? or how do I complete it?

Comment: You haven't proved anything yet.

Comment: Note that a_n is a cauchy sequence.

Comment: Don’t put the full question only in the title.

Comment: The statement is false so it cannot be proven. You can only give a counterexample which shows it is false. The line you wrote "$a_n$ converges to $a_nb_n$" makes no sense; a sequence does not converge to another sequence. A sequence converges to a number.

Comment: @Rei D Gar - If you modify your example slightly, say $a_n =c$ for all $n,$ where $c$ is a nonzero constant, and keep your sequence $b=\{b_n\}$ the same, you have provided an example to show that if the sequence $a = \{a_n\}$ does not converge to zero, then the sequence $ab$ cannot converge in general. Sourav Ghosh's answer provides the proof for what happens when $a_n \rightarrow 0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n \}$ two two sequence such that
$\{a_n\}\to 0 $ and $\{b_n\}$ is bounded, then $\{a_n b_n \}\to 0 $

Proof : There exists $K>0 $ such that $|b_n|<K $ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

Again, given any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N$

$|a_n|<\frac{\epsilon }{K} $

Proof : \begin{align} |a_n b_n -0 |&= |a_n| |b_n|<\frac{\epsilon }{K}•K =\epsilon \space \space \forall n>N\end{align}

Hence, $\{a_n b_n \}\to 0 $

If $\{a_n\} $ converges to $a\neq 0$ , then the sequence $\{a_n b_n \}$ may not converge.

Example : $(a_n )=\{1,1,1,...\}$ and $b_n=\{(-1)^n\}$

Then $\{a_n\}$ is convergent and $\{b_n\}$ is bounded but $\{a_n b_n\}=\{(-1)^n\}$ is not convergent.

Comment: and how can I prove that?